# Servo make partial rotation and stop working automatically

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, adafruit, voltage

I'm using this board in my robotic arm project:
**Adafruit PCA9685 16-Channel Servo Driver** (
https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver/using-the-adafruit-library)

I've connected all of my servo and now I'm trying to calibrating each one.

This is my configuration:

---

**Setup**

```
pwm = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver(0x40);
pwm.begin();
pwm.setOscillatorFrequency(27000000);
pwm.setPWMFreq(50);
```

**Movement**

```
pwm.setPWM(pinPosition, 0, power);
```

The `power` is mapped using `map` and **minPulse** and **maxPulse** based on this data structure:

```
ServoSettings servo0 = ServoSettings{ 
   0,   // pinPosition
   125,  // minPulse
   400, // maxPulse
   125  // currentPWM
};
```

I'm using `minPulse` and `maxPulse` for calibration and `currentPWM` to store data for each servo.
Data is sended through iPhone via BLE.

---

My servo, start rotating from **125** to **~280** and returns to back and stopped working. I need to power off my board and move the servo from its 0 position just to make movements again.

I don't understand two things:

1. why the rotation is not 180° but about 45°?
2. why after 45° servo come back home and stop working?

I suppose that is due to a wrong Adafruit library configuration but of course I'm not sure.

---

Using a manual loop instead of BLE data, result is the same:
`moveServo` is a wrapper of `pwm.setPWM(pinPosition, 0, power)`

```
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 90);
  Serial.println("0");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 125);
  Serial.println("A");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 145);
  Serial.println("B");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 190);
  Serial.println("C");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 220);
  Serial.println("D");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 250);
  Serial.println("E");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 280); // <<<--- here servo come back home and die.
  Serial.println("F");
  delay(1500);
  servoMgr.moveServo(0, 300);
  Serial.println("G");
```

---

The **Adafruit board** is powered with an **external 9V battery**.
**Arduino** is powered with **USB** cable.

Can be something **related to voltage**?
What's wrong with the library configuration?

The board now have only 1 servo attached, just for test.

These are the used servo: https://www.amazon.it/dp/B07KD6NVPM

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Just to check: You are not using the standard 9V block batteries?

Comment: Like this one: https://www.amazon.it/Duracell-Plus-Power-6LP3146-Transistor/dp/B004W7GYGQ/

Comment: These 9V block batteries are made for low power applications. They cannot provide much current. It might well be the problem. Please try a better power supply, for example a 9V wallwart (just to test this), or some AA batteries in series

Comment: Thanks @chrisl, I’ll try.